# Create a Joint in Box2D from bodies in separate functions

Tags: function, flash, box2d

I've been stuck for three days on this.

I create two bodies in two separate functions. Each function returns the body.

```
function createPlayerBody():b2Body
        {

                bd.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
                box = new b2PolygonShape();
                box.SetAsBox(50 / PIXELS_TO_METRE, 25 / PIXELS_TO_METRE);
                fixtureDef.shape = box;
                bodyfixtureDef.shape = box;
                fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = MASK_PLAYER;
                fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
                fixtureDef.friction = 0.4;
                fixtureDef.restitution = 0.1;
                bd.position.Set(startX / PIXELS_TO_METRE, (startY + 32) / PIXELS_TO_METRE);
                var torso1:b2Body = _world.CreateBody(bd);

                torso1.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);
                torso1.CreateFixture(bodyfixtureDef);


                return torso1;


        }


        public function createPlayer():b2Body
        {

                // Head
                bd.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
                box = new b2PolygonShape();
                fixtureDef.shape = box;
                bodyfixtureDef.shape = box;
                fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = MASK_PLAYER;
                fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
                fixtureDef.friction = 0.4;
                fixtureDef.restitution = 0.3;
                box.SetAsBox(36 / PIXELS_TO_METRE, 25 / PIXELS_TO_METRE);
                bd.position.Set(startX / PIXELS_TO_METRE, startY / PIXELS_TO_METRE);
                var head:b2Body = _world.CreateBody(bd);

                head.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);
                head.CreateFixture(bodyfixtureDef);

                //_balls.push(new Ball(createPlayerBody(), new PlayerBody()));              
                //var body = createPlayerBody();
                return head;


        }
```

Very straightforward. But now I want to make a joint between them. It is not possible. I have tried about 25 different methods people have suggested to access the torso1 and head variables. But they are always NULL.

Here is the code to create a joint.

```
jd.lowerAngle = -40 / (180/Math.PI);
                jd.upperAngle = 40 / (180/Math.PI);
                jd.Initialize(body, head, new b2Vec2(startX / PIXELS_TO_METRE, (startY + 15) / PIXELS_TO_METRE));
                _world.CreateJoint(jd);
```

I have been reading books, looking for some way for this to be allowed to happen.

The problem is the functions are called with an extra parameter (texture) so they can't be changed or merged.

```
_objects.push(new Object(createPlayer(), new PlayerImage()));
_objects.push(new Object(createPlayerBody(), new PlayerBody()));
```

I have tried setting the head variable to equal the function, but then I can't include the texture parameter. I have tried every way to make them global or universally accessible but it does not work in this case. I suspect the variables are destroyed as soon as the function finishes. I scoured the lists of variables and even printed out 14 pages of variables and didn't see 'head' or 'torso1' anywhere.

I want to know why I can't access them. I want to know what I need to put before the variable to access it.

I tried Object:head, _object:head, _world._body._m_world.GetBody(), GetBody(head). b2Body:head, head:b2Body, Object:b2Body.head and many others. I tried putting the functions in a separate file. I tried putting them in the Object class. I tried private, public, static functions. I'm out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you execute both your functions. Then get the last two items in the array.

```
var objectA: Ball = _object[_object.length-1];
var objectB: Ball = _object[_object.length-2];
```

And initialize the joint like so.

```
jd.Initialize(objectA.body, objectB.body new b2Vec2(startX / PIXELS_TO_METRE, (startY + 15) / PIXELS_TO_METRE));
```